# Foundation 6 - how to destroy reveal from the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, custom-data-attribute

I have some issues with reveal initializing in foundation 6. I am trying to create a new instance for #menu on medium and small screens and remove it on large. I have problems to remove data-attributes that comes with data-reveal.

```
$(function () {
  responsiveMenu();

  function responsiveMenu() {
    if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('large')) {
      $('#menu').removeAttr('data-reveal', '').removeClass('full reveal');
    } else {
      var event = new Foundation.Reveal($('#menu').addClass('full reveal'));
    }
  }

  $(window).on('changed.zf.mediaquery', function (event, large) {
    responsiveMenu();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `class="show-for-small-only show-for-medium-only"` class in your menu ? else `class="hide-for-large-only"`

Comment: My question was not about how to hide menu ;) I want to display menu in reveal modal, so my point is how to create and destroy reveal for #menu using jQuery. I don't want to double my code, but use javascript to handle menu in the way it is opened on reveal overlay when < large.

Comment: After initializing event, I would like to remove it from #menu with all the given reveal attributes, to display menu correctly when the window size change.

I was trying to use Reveal.destroy but it seems, that this function doesn't remove  reveal at all.

Comment: Make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s7fab3v9/

Comment: You want to close and open a popup using JS ?

Comment: Not at all, I keep menu in one div, that I would like to toggle between the state when it is a reveal modal (for small & medium screens) and not (large screens). The problem is, when I once initialize reveal for small screens, I can not  destroy it for large.

Comment: I am still not getting your question

Comment: Okey I would like to toggle when resizing browser window between 2 states of div#menu.

https://jsfiddle.net/r88ku2ns/

The problem is that when I once initialize Reveal, I can not dispose of other attributes that Reveal attach to the div#menu.

Comment: Have you catch my idea? If it is not clear I would try explain in one more time. HEEELP :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(function () {
  responsiveMenu();

  function responsiveMenu() {
    if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('large')) {
      $('.reveal-overlay').remove();
    } else {
      var event = new Foundation.Reveal($('#menu').addClass('full reveal'));
    }
  }

  $(window).on('changed.zf.mediaquery', function (event, large) {
    responsiveMenu();
  });
});
```